# Google Directory API is not strong signed

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client, google-directory-api

BEFORE ANY OF YOU CLAIM THIS IS NOT WHERE THE API IS SUPPORTED PLEASE SEE THIS LINK:  https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/support

Peleyal: This is probably not the best place to have your support site; all I get are people that down vote because this is "not the place to get support on an API" according to the rules....

Well, I got everything working in my library with the new API then I stumbled on this little gem while importing it into my code base...

Error 4 Assembly generation failed -- Referenced assembly 'Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1' does not have a strong name
Error 5 Assembly generation failed -- Referenced assembly 'Google.Apis.Auth.PlatformServices' does not have a strong name
Error 6 Assembly generation failed -- Referenced assembly 'Google.Apis' does not have a strong name Error 7 Assembly generation failed -- Referenced assembly 'Google.Apis.Core' does not have a strong name
Error 8 Assembly generation failed -- Referenced assembly 'Google.Apis' does not have a strong name Error 9 Assembly generation failed -- Referenced assembly 'Google.Apis.Core' does not have a strong name

According to the stack overflow on third party assemblies.... Third party DLL does not have 'strong name'?

But I'm not sending a "nasty gram", but rather a plea. Can we get this assembly signed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry for the late response, and I'm sorry to bring the bad news: There is already an open issue for this one - https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/detail?id=238, and yeah it's old. We will try to finally address this one in the next release, but I can't give any concrete estimations. 
 By the way, we will have to address one of the dependencies which as far as I know isn't signed first - [ZLib.Portable](https://github.com/advancedrei/Zlib.Portable).

Anyway, you can sign it yourself, with your version, because the library is open source. The core library code is available here: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/, and the Google Admin Directory API is in https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/download/admin/directory_v1/csharp.

Comment: As a side note, the old google API is signed and it is also using the ZLib.Portable...

Comment: Which Google APIs library do you mean?

Comment: The old, deprecated libraries

Comment: Can you share a link please? I'm confused, do you mean the gdata library?

Comment: I installed this from nuget and zlib came with it.  https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/
this API also is strong signed; well at least it compiles into my signed application with no issues.

Comment: I was able to sign everything.... 

I tried to sign the google APIs with ilasm but because the zlib.portable was in there I got an error when I tried to link the code over.  

So what I did was to use ilasm to sign the zlib.portable without downloading their source code then linked that into your google api libraries and signed the google core apis and then the admin api.

After that I used nuget to add the google.apis and then removed the references and added in the newly signed references.

Problems went away.

It sure would be VERY nice to have a signed API......

Comment: I agree, and sorry for everything you had to deal with. I think it's important that the Zlib.Portable dll will be signed by owner and not by us, so we will have to wait for their signing first. I already contacted the owner, and currently waiting for a response.

Comment: Can I just ask how did you solve the signing issue? I managed to sign all the DLLs I downloaded from NuGet and my signed DLL in Visual Studio compiles fine. Issue is, when I use it in another application, I get an error since the InternalsVisibleTo declaration on some of these DLLs does not obivously) include my key. Is there a way to solve this? Thank you

Comment: That wont work because the gapi is using another package that is not signed.  Everything has to be signed to work...  So, download the source, nuget the additional packages.  Sign the zlib.dll with ilasm then apply a certificate (a self signed or dev certificate will work) to the google source and compile.

Comment: I removed my previous comment as I think I just need to download more source projects form Google to successfully open the in VS and then edit to my needs

Comment: I was a rather big task to import the project into VS...  There were a lot of things that needed to be resolved by hand.  Just a FYI...  You only need to download the two API sources...

Comment: I just heard from the guys behind Zlib.Portable dll they are looking into signing it.   Sounds like they thought they had already signed it.